# How can I generate a random number each time the android starts up or restarted, using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've tried using the following code:
`var testNumber: Int = (0..4).random()`
I also attempted the following code:
`var testNumber: Int = Random.nextInt(0, 5)`
However, the generated number remains the same whenever I run the app.

Comment: Just pass the seed to random function `(0..4).random(Random(System.nanoTime()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Kotlin are you using? [There's a bug in *1.6.21*](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52618/ThreadLocalRandom-is-not-a-good-source-of-randomness-on-Android-before-SDK-34-so-dont-use-it-for-Kotlin-Random) (and possibly other versions after *1.5*) where some versions of Android produce the same "random" sequences after a reboot, because of how Android handles `ThreadLocalRandom`.

If you're using an affected version, try upgrading your Kotlin Gradle plugin to at least *1.7.20*. If you can't do that for whatever reason, you might want to use `java.util.random.Random` as a source of randomness instead